# static final fields vs TrustFinalNonStaticFields

Tags: java, jvm, jit, java-15

Suppose I have this simple method:

```
static final Integer me = Integer.parseInt("2");

static int go() {
    return me * 2;
}
```

For javac, `me` is not a constant (according to the JLS rules), but for JIT most probably is.

I tried to test this with:

```
 public class StaticFinal {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int hash = 0;
        for(int i=0;i<1000_000;++i){
            hash = hash ^ go();
        }
        System.out.println(hash);
    }

    static final Integer me = Integer.parseInt("2");

    static int go() {
        return me * 2;
    }
}
```

And running it with:

```
  java -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions 
       -XX:-TieredCompilation  
       "-XX:CompileCommand=print,StaticFinal.go"  
       -XX:PrintAssemblyOptions=intel  
       StaticFinal.java
```

I do not know assembly very good, but this is obvious:

```
mov    eax,0x4
```

The result of `go` is immediately `4`, i.e.: JIT "trusted" `me` to be a constant, thus `2 * 2 = 4`.

If I drop `static` and change the code to:

```
public class NonStaticFinal {

    static NonStaticFinal instance = new NonStaticFinal();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int hash = 0;
        for(int i=0;i<1000_000;++i){
            hash = hash ^ instance.go();
        }
        System.out.println(hash);
    }

    final Integer me = Integer.parseInt("2");

    int go() {
        return me * 2;
    }
}
```

And run that with:

```
java -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions 
     -XX:-TieredCompilation  
     "-XX:CompileCommand=print,NonStaticFinal.go"  
     -XX:PrintAssemblyOptions=intel  
     NonStaticFinal.java
```

I do see in assembly:

```
shl    eax,1
```

which is actually the multiplication of `me` with `2`, done via a shift. So JIT did not trust `me` to be a constant, which is kind of expected.

And now the question. I thought that if I add `TrustFinalNonStaticFields` flag, I will see the same `mov eax 0x4`, i.e.: running with:

```
 java -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions 
      -XX:-TieredCompilation  
      "-XX:CompileCommand=print,NonStaticFinal.go"  
      -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions 
      -XX:+TrustFinalNonStaticFields 
      -XX:PrintAssemblyOptions=intel  
      NonStaticFinal.java
```

should reveal `mov    eax,0x4`, but to my surprise it does not, and the code stays as:

```
shl    eax,1
```

Can someone explain what is going on and what I am missing?

Comment: By the way, the VM trusts non-static final fields in records and hidden classes, AFAIK. But you still need a "static final root".

Comment: Johannes is right, about records as well. See [`ciField::trust_final_non_static_fields`](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/hotspot/share/ci/ciField.cpp#L219) for the criteria of implicitly trusted final instance fields (notice how the `if` chain bottoms out in `return TrustFinalNonStaticFields`).

Comment: @JornVernee Some questions about the linked code: 1) Shouldn't it only check non-static final fields? jl.System does not have any instances - or instance members. 2) Is jl.String not in the java.lang package? 3) Are the box classes not in java.lang?

Comment: @JohannesKuhn Both seem to be cruft (AFAICS); [At the time the j.l.System exclude was added](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/commit/8214fc3a3bcd0949f5c8a28f61faaa67f87a7522) there were no instance fields in System either, and the check is only used for non-static fields. The `java/lang` include was added as part of the first memory-access API incubator in JDK 14. I don't know off the top of my head why `java/lang` was added, but any way, it seems the cleanup of the cases for j.l.String and the box classes was missed at that time.

Comment: Thanks @JornVernee. Was my suspicion, but I don't understand enough of the code to even suggest any action. So I just ask stupid questions, so I may at some point be able to do that.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`TrustFinalNonStaticFields` enables folding of `final` instance fields from constant objects. In your example however, the `instance` field is non constant, so folding the load of the `me` field is not correct, since the `instance` object might still be changed at some point after compilation.

Furthermore, you're printing out the assembly for the `go` method, where `this` will not be seen as a constant if the method is compiled in isolation. To see the effect of `TrustFinalNonStaticFields` you need to look at the assembly for an inlined version of the `go` method, where the receiver is a constant. For instance:

```
 public class NonStaticFinal {

    static final NonStaticFinal instance = new NonStaticFinal();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 20_000; i++) { // trigger compilation of 'payload'
            payload();
        }
    }
    
    static int payload() {
        return instance.go();
    }

    final Integer me = Integer.parseInt("2");

    int go() {
        return me * 2;
    }

}
```

Running with:

```
java 
  -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions 
  -XX:-TieredCompilation
  "-XX:CompileCommand=print,NonStaticFinal.payload"
  "-XX:CompileCommand=dontinline,NonStaticFinal.payload"
  -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions
  -XX:+TrustFinalNonStaticFields
  -XX:PrintAssemblyOptions=intel
  -Xbatch
  NonStaticFinal.java
```

Produces assembly where we can see the load + multiplication of the `me` field is being folded in the `payload` method:

```
  # {method} {0x0000016238c59470} 'payload' '()I' in 'NonStaticFinal'
  #           [sp+0x20]  (sp of caller)
  // set up frame
  0x00000162283d2500:   sub     rsp,18h
  0x00000162283d2507:   mov     qword ptr [rsp+10h],rbp     ;*synchronization entry
                                                            ; - NonStaticFinal::payload@-1 (line 12)
  // load a constant 4
  0x00000162283d250c:   mov     eax,4h     <-------------
  // clean up frame
  0x00000162283d2511:   add     rsp,10h
  0x00000162283d2515:   pop     rbp
  // safepoint poll
  0x00000162283d2516:   mov     r10,qword ptr [r15+110h]
  0x00000162283d251d:   test    dword ptr [r10],eax         ;   {poll_return}
  // return
  0x00000162283d2520:   ret
```

---

Compared to the version where TFNSF is disabled, where the load of the `me` field still occurs:

```
  # {method} {0x00000245f9669470} 'payload' '()I' in 'NonStaticFinal'
  #           [sp+0x20]  (sp of caller)
  // stack bang
  0x00000245e8d52a00:   mov     dword ptr [rsp+0ffffffffffff9000h],eax
  // set up frame
  0x00000245e8d52a07:   push    rbp
  0x00000245e8d52a08:   sub     rsp,10h                     ;*synchronization entry
                                                            ; - NonStaticFinal::payload@-1 (line 12)
  // load the 'instance' field. It's a constant, so the address here is constant
  0x00000245e8d52a0c:   mov     r10,70ff107a8h              ;   {oop(a 'NonStaticFinal'{0x000000070ff107a8})}
  // load the (compressed) oop 'me' field at 0ch (first field after the object header)
  0x00000245e8d52a16:   mov     r11d,dword ptr [r10+0ch]    ;*getfield me {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
                                                            ; - NonStaticFinal::go@1 (line 18)
                                                            ; - NonStaticFinal::payload@3 (line 12)
  // Load the 'value' field from the Integer object.
  // r12 is the heap base, r11 the compressed oop 'Integer', *8 here to uncompress it,
  // and again loading the first field after the header at 0ch
  0x00000245e8d52a1a:   mov     eax,dword ptr [r12+r11*8+0ch]; implicit exception: dispatches to 0x00000245e8d52a31
  // multiply by 2
  // ABI returns ints in the 'eax' register, so no need to shuffle afterwards
  0x00000245e8d52a1f:   shl     eax,1h                      ;*imul {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
                                                            ; - NonStaticFinal::go@8 (line 18)
                                                            ; - NonStaticFinal::payload@3 (line 12)
  // clean up frame
  0x00000245e8d52a21:   add     rsp,10h
  0x00000245e8d52a25:   pop     rbp
  // safepoint poll
  0x00000245e8d52a26:   mov     r10,qword ptr [r15+110h]
  0x00000245e8d52a2d:   test    dword ptr [r10],eax         ;   {poll_return}
  // return
  0x00000245e8d52a30:   ret
```